# Go language cannot use r (type *mux.Router) as type *mux.Route in return argument

Tags: go, servemux

Hi i am initializing Router in other Go file and returning reference of it in Main file and then in Main file i am initializing serve.
This piece of code is not compiling

```
package router

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "binapp/controllers"
)

const all_bin string = "/bin"

func InitRouter() (*mux.Route) {
    r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

    r.HandleFunc(all_bin, controllers.BinController)

    return r
}


package main

import (
    "binapp/router"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    router := router.InitRouter()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9096", router))
}
```

I am getting error as:

```
# binapp/router
binapp/router/Route.go:15: cannot use r (type *mux.Router) as type *mux.Route in return argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type for `InitRouter` is wrong. You return a `*mux.Router` but specify a return type of `*mux.Route`.

Comment: Y Y Y on this earth i did commit that mistake. I am locking myself in bathroom for an hour now.